# Gradient Descent for Linear Regression not minimizing perfectly

Tags: c++, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the basic gradient descent algorithm on my uniformly distributed training set. As the data is uniform so the partition line should be diagonal, but i am getting a line as in below figure. In the figure circles are my data points and the line represent the cost function(h(x)). [image: Figure 1]

> I am using OpenCV just for output nothing else. I am using below equation:-

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#define WIN_WIDTH 500
#define WIN_HEIGHT 500
#define MAX_POINTS 500

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void getPoints(vector<Point> &randPoints, int size)
{
  for (int i = 20; i < WIN_HEIGHT; i+=20)
  {
    for (int j = 20; j < WIN_WIDTH; j+=20)
    {
      int x = i;
      int y = j;

      Point pt = Point(x, y);

      randPoints.push_back(pt);
    }
  }
}

void gradientDescent( double &th1,  double &th2,  double &alpha, vector<Point> &pointVec)
{
    int size = pointVec.size();

    double sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum1 += (th1 + th2 * pointVec[i].x) - pointVec[i].y;
        sum2 += ((th1 + th2 * pointVec[i].x) - pointVec[i].y) * pointVec[i].x;
    }

    th1 = th1 - ((alpha/( double)size) * sum1);
    th2 = th2 - ((alpha/( double)size) * sum2);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Mat img(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, CV_8UC3);
    img = Scalar(255, 255, 255);

    vector<Point> randPoints;
    getPoints(randPoints, MAX_POINTS);

    int size = randPoints.size();

    cout << "Training size = " << randPoints.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        circle(img, randPoints[i], 4, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1, 8);

   double theta1 = 0, theta2 = 0.25, alpha = 0.0000001; 

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        theta1 = atof(argv[1]);
        theta2 = atof(argv[2]);
    }

    int countConv = 0, prevY = 0;

    cout << "Theta0 = " << theta1 << " Theta1 = " << theta2 << endl;
    cout << "Learning rate = " << alpha << endl;

    Mat tmpImg(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, CV_8UC3);

    while(1)
    {
        gradientDescent(theta1, theta2, alpha, randPoints);  

        int x = WIN_WIDTH+WIN_HEIGHT;
        int y = theta1 + (theta2 * x);

        int x1 = WIN_WIDTH-200;
        int y1 = theta1 + theta2*x1;

        img.copyTo(tmpImg);

        circle(tmpImg, Point(x1, y1), 4, Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1, 8);

        char text[64];
        sprintf(text, "(%d, %d)", x1, y1);

        putText(tmpImg, text, Point(x1+3, y1+3), FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 0.4, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8);

        line(tmpImg, Point(0, theta1), Point(x, y), Scalar(0, 0, 255));

        imshow("Gradient Descent", tmpImg);
        waitKey(33);
    }

    imshow("Gradient Descent", tmpImg);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a square the line connecting opposite corners is diagonal, so clearly that line is not a diagonal.  Pls read the code at least before commenting and ask if something is not clear and most important try to help..

Comment: what do you mean by _point 3_ and which are hardcoded constants, if you are talking about `theta1`, `theta2` and `alpha` then these are input to my gradient descent function, `theta1` and `theta2` are passed by **reference** so in the main function  i am always having updated values of `thete1` and `theta2`.

Comment: Hi @danishansari, you are supposed to iterate right? Gradient descent does not converge after the first step. I see a while loop, but you did not specify at what iteration the image was captured (I mean the one with the non-diagonal) line.

Comment: @VihariPiratla It is taking 700-800 iterations in ~30 secs to reach this non-diagonal line, and after that is not not converging any more, this is the final state.

Comment: Your alpha is very small. What happens when you use something like `0.01` ?

Comment: I did read your code, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to make my 3rd comment. Regarding the diagonal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal *Informally, any sloping line is called diagonal.*

Comment: From my perspective it seems like you do not have a clear view of what problem you are trying to solve. This is what I'm asking you to think about, and then clarify. Regarding constants, the line you are plotting is hardcoded here `Point(0, theta1)` and here `Point(x, y)` where `x = WIN_WIDTH+WIN_HEIGHT`. Your cost-function suggests you are attempting to optimize something like `ax + b` where `a=theta2, b=theta1`, but you use it in a different way.

Comment: @toasted_flakes alpha = 0.01 is causing overshoot, and it never converge, i have actually started with 0.01, 0.001... and so on

Comment: @AskeDoerge i am pretty clear about the problem, as the data is uniform the gradient descent should give me a diagonal, because only diagonal will give me min squared error(i.e. 0) over the uniform data. I am using `x = WIN_WIDTH+WIN_HEIGHT` so that my line should be greater than diagonal and yes this line has the equation `y = theta1 + theta2 * x` same as y = mx+c

Comment: Hmm. Why is it not `int x = WIN_WIDTH;`? It seems you are calculating the coords for the second point in a place way off screen.

Comment: yes it is way off screen, but it is not making any difference, you can take `x = WIN_WIDTH` or `x = WIN_HEIGHT` or `x = R(any real number)`. You will get different values of y with different x's but all points(x, y) will be on the same line.

Comment: I think the code is correct, i have tested it on sample data and the output is matched. May be due to input data(spread over a large scale) some how its not showing perfect diagonal.